# Filters in the View of My list having no effect

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm stuck, it seems no matter which filter I apply to my view, the the filter doesn't work.  I try various filters like:

[image]

or:

[image]

The list always shows all items.  It's as if no matter what filters I choose, they aren't applied.  Any ideas?  Any thoughts on where to look?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Is the "completed" field corresponds to status of workflow?

Comment: No, it's a default field of the Task item.  Which is Yes/No.  Funny thing is no matter what filters I choose, they don't take effect.  Oddly when I export the list to Excel The filter is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This triggers an error, "Filter value is not a valid Yes/No value.  Please specify 'Yes' or 'No'.

Comment: Well! [Me] is working for me. Sorry I couldn't help you. Can you add more screenshots if possible?

Comment: it seems so far to be a microsoft bug, as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659969/cannot-filter-a-sharepoint-2013-task-list-after-march-2015-update  This is the exact issue I'm seeing.